# JS custom functions are not listed in "Insert Function" dialog

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

Thanks to the [Excel-Custom-Functions](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions) sample I can use the new JS functions in Excel, e.g. insert `=CONTOSO.ADD42(1;2)`

But in Excels Insert Function dialog the `CONTOSO` functions cannot be found.

I would expect to see `CONTOSO` in the list of categories, and all of its functions within this category.

Is there additional coding required to see these functions in the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't enabled any features for extending the Insert Function dialog yet. So for now you'd have to rely on our existing ribbon extensibility framework ("add-in commands", which lets you add ribbon buttons to any tab or create a new tab. Thank you for the feedback!

-Michael, PM for add-ins